# Can't edit/change url product/category magento 1.9.1

Tags: magento

I have edited the URL key in the backend:

`category-old` to `category-new`,  `product-old` changed to `product-new`

Then refreshed Cache but url `category/product` on frontend still shows no change.

> domain.com/category-old.html - worked
>
> domain.com/category-new.html - Error 404

Any help, or suggestions?. thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to refreshing the cache, you will need to reindex for these changes to show.

Go to shell folder in your Magento installation:

```
cd shell
```

Execute reindex using this command:

```
php indexer.php reindexall
```

Comment: Thank @WombleGold. can i reindex in System -> Index Management?

Comment: Yes, it does the same thing.